# django form wizard, does not go to second step

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to perform the following using Django :

- Wizard containing two formds
- First form is a simple form containing some Ajax to compute automatically some fields
- Second form is a user registration

The problem is the following :

- The first form is displayed correctly and the Ajax within the page is working fine
- The second form is never displayed after pushing on the button "submit"

The code is as follows :

**urls.py**

```
from forms import InsertPropertyForm1, InsertPropertyForm2
from views import InsertPropertyWizard

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^addProperty/$',  InsertPropertyWizard.as_view([InsertPropertyForm1, InsertPropertyForm2]), name='addProperty'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
FORMS = [("property", InsertPropertyForm1),
     ("test", InsertPropertyForm2)         
    ]
TEMPLATES = {'0': 'realEstate/addProperty.html',
         '1' : 'realEstate/test.html',             
         }

class InsertPropertyWizard(SessionWizardView):

  def get_template_names(self):        
    print ("next step !!!!! " + str(self.steps.current))
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

  def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    print "Wizard done"
    #do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://TO_FILL_IN')
```

**realEstate/addProperty.html**

```
{% extends 'realEstate/base.html' %}
{% load socialaccount %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<h1> Insert an ad </h1>

<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>

<form  class="form-horizontal" role="form"  action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

<table>

  {{ wizard.management_form }}

</table>

{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<fieldset>
  <legend>Localisation</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.country.errors }}
      <label class="col-lg-1" for="id_country">{{form.country.label}}</label>
      <div class="col-lg-1">
        {{ form.country }}
      </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

</fieldset>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}
  </button>
  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}
  </button>
{% endif %}

<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>

</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you use ajax fields? Do you save the values somehere?

Comment: Hi mariodev, I am using ajax to call services on the server when some fields are changed. I am not changing the fields which are automatically created by the wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought it could help someone.

Problem was that one of the field was not defined in the form and I forgot to include it in the template.

The behaviour of the wizard was correct. It got stuc on the first page but did not display the error on the screen as the field was not displayed.

Got me crazy but it was my fault.

Cheers